# How to solve ConcurrentModificationException in GoogleMaps in Android

Tags: java, android

I have written code for displaying multiple markers in GoogleMaps in android. My code is as follows.

```
List<Overlay> markersList;
private MyItemizedOverlay funPlaces;
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (markersList != null) {
                MapController mc = mapView.getController();
                mc.setZoom(15);
                for (int i=0; i < markersList.size(); i++) {
                    funPlaces = (MyItemizedOverlay) markersList.get(i);
                    GeoPoint pt = funPlaces.getCenterPt();
                    mc.setCenter(pt);
                    mapView.postInvalidate();
                }
            }
        }
    };
Thread t=new Thread(r,"ClassName");
t.start();
```

When I'm running the above code sometimes it is working fine but sometimes it is giving ConcurrentModificationException. How to fix this problem? Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your question. Your question should help others too and is hard to read. I would also recommend to take a look at [how and why you should accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169719).

Comment: On which line is the exception?  What is the stack trace?

Comment: Wow, 8% answer rate. You're not encouraging people to answer.

Comment: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:44)
com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:494)
android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
 android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)

Answer (score 1):

If that's where you're getting the error, you're almost certainly modifying an ArrayList while an iteration is in progress.  I can't tell from the code you've provided whether that's due to actual concurrency, or just performing modifications on an ArrayList during your iteration, but that's going to be the reason.

Comment: yes i understand the problem.Do you have solution for the problem

Comment: Without seeing the part of the code that's actually failing?  Only "rearrange your code so that you aren't modifying the ArrayList through anything but the iterator."  Or if it's actually due to concurrency, use something like CopyOnWriteArrayList that's meant to be used concurrently.